# How to sum a range of cells in between a specific value multiple times?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically I have a dynamic range of values that is recalculated everyday. I want to be able to have a sum value for every interval with a value greater than zero. Sorry if that is confusing. I will illustrate to clarify.

Starting in A1

```
0
0
0
5
4
2
0
0
1
0
```

I would like to have the following starting in B1:

```
0
0
0
11
11
11
0
0
1
0
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far in terms of summing a dynamic range?

Answer (score 1):

If your first zero is in A1 then put this in B1 and dfa it down (or double-click the 'fill handle').

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:1)/(A$1:A1=0), 1)):
       INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)+1))/(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99, A:A)+1)=0), 1)))
```

[image]